# Display Row Values based on Nearest Numeric Match of Key

Tags: excel, vba

Say I have a sorted list of values in column A.  They serve as a 'key' to each numerical row.  Something like this:

```
   ___A_(key)_______B______         ______G_____
1 |____2.58___|____________|   ... |____________|   ... 
2 |____2.69___|____________|   ... |____________|   ...
        ...         ...                  ...
   ________________________         ____________
x |____5.69___|____________|   ... |____________|   ...
```

Columns B through G have some values for each of the keys, so it's basically a 2D spreadsheet of numerical data.

I need to be able to quickly access a certain row by the **approximate** value.

Right now I have set a Filter on the column, and can search for the rows, but for that I need to enter the key value exactly, i.e. `2.58`, or `2.69`, but not something like `2.64`.

I want to be able to enter something like `2.64`, and have the row with nearest key value be shown to me, preferably in a separate location, such as on the side of the table, like starting in column I where exactly can be defined, but basically any method where I type in a value and get conveniently shown the row values will do.  How can I do this?

My experience level is:  I did some simple stuff in VBA/excel ~10 years ago... and basically looking for a good starting direction and approach.

Comment: as a start point, look into [this answer by @BK201](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864282/any-way-to-script-excel-to-run-a-fancy-search-for-multiple-queries-at-once/21864614#21864614). For approximate match use third parametr of `Match` function equal to `1` (instead `0`)

Comment: @simoco that can give you the closest higher or lower, but not closest.

Comment: While `MATCH` seems fine, I agree with @user2140261. If I use it with `2.51` it's going to `N/A` on the above at third parameter `=1`, even if data is sorted ascendingly. I think this is best dealt with VBA. :/

Comment: add a row with key 0? :)

Comment: @BK201, agree, VBA would be simpliest way, but you could also find min difference using array formula `=MIN(ABS(A1:A10-2.51))` and add it (or substract) to (from) 2.51 (it's possible to detect add or substract with simple if formula). And the use `Match` function to find `2.51+MIN(ABS(A1:A10-2.51))` with third parametr `0` (exact match)

Comment: Indeed it is possible that way. Curses, VBA, you've made me a lazy guy! :D

Comment: @simoco Didn't even see your comment till now, I think we are on the same path, that's basically how I answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your Data is in `A1:A20` and your look up value is in `B1` this formula will return the closest:

```
=INDEX(A1:A20,MATCH(MIN(ABS(A1:A20-B1)),ABS(A1:A20-B1),0))
```

When entering make sure to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> 
and **NOT** just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

It is getting the smallest difference then returning its row into the index, index then returns the value.

Comment: great answer, but incomplete with respect to my question.  I need to have the row displayed, so need to add `=VLOOKUP(H2,A1:B20,2)`, `=VLOOKUP(H2,A1:B20,3)`, etc. for each column I wanted to have displayed, where H2 in this case is the result of the INDEX formula

Comment: @Dennis No, not at all all you have to do is change the very first A1:A20 to the column that you want returned. and that's all. So for the value in column B on the row with the closest value in A in comparison to B1 would be `=INDEX(B1:B20,MATCH(MIN(ABS(A1:A20-B1)),ABS(A1:A20-B1),0))` all that changes is the first reference. The whole part of the formula `MATCH(MIN(ABS(A1:A20-B1)),ABS(A1:A20-B1),0)` is simply returning the number of the row with the closest match, You also could put your entire range in the first reference and use the column index part of the index to return the column

Comment: for example you could reference A1:D10 and return the value in the third column (in this case C) of the table on the same row that has the closest match in column A by using the following: `=INDEX(A1:D20,MATCH(MIN(ABS(A1:A20-B1)),ABS(A1:A20-B1),0), 3)` , notice the 3 at the end that is the column reference in respect to the first range reference `A1:D20`

Comment: Question:  Let's say I have column E that contains unsorted numbers from the set {1, 2, 3}.  Is there a way to update the formula above to ONLY consider selecting closest rows of A to where E equals to 1?  aka consider only rows where values of E are equal to the given number, say 1 in this example?

Comment: @Dennis Absolutely, I think that is better for another question then a comment though, ask a new question I'm sure you'll get an answer.

Comment: Question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391015/need-a-complex-excel-lookup-using-a-filter-on-one-column-and-finding-closest

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm thinking, You loop through all the rows and get the difference between your target and the value in that cell. You find the row that gives the least difference and that will be your target row.

```
Dim dblErr As Double
Dim intIndex As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim dblTarget As Double

dblTarget = 'Value you are after
dblErr = 10000 ' or some other large number
For i = 1 To x 'x= number of rows
    If dblErr > Abs(Cells(i + 1, 1) - dblTarget) Then
        dblErr = Abs(Cells(i + 1, 1) - dblTarget)
        intIndex = i
    End If
Next i

Ans = Cells(intIndex, 1)
```