# How to make Excel consider ONLY rows that have a given value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

Here is an image, followed by description of data
[image]

Description of Columns:

- Column A (Key) is strictly increasing sequence of decimals
- Column B (Group) represents a group the value in A belongs to.
- Column C (Data) is assorted data

Inputs (in column F)

- Exact Group number in i.e. {1, 2, 3, 4} in F4
- A decimal value (unrestricted), call it `DecimalValue`, in F5

Task

Find row that belongs to the given `Group`, where ABS(`Key` - `DecimalValue`) value is minimized.  Return `Data` from that row.

- Ideally looking for an Excel-only solution, using INDEX, VLOOKUP,
  ABS, and the like.

This question is similar to my previous question, but different enough (involves a new `Group`column), where via comments it was determined that it is best to ask a new question, rather than try to update / modify the existing question:

[Display Row Values based on Nearest Numeric Match of Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918877/display-row-values-based-on-nearest-numeric-match-of-key)

Adding correction for `Group` column, if it is possible is what I am after, hence the title reflects that concern.

**(Incomplete Solution - does not consider `Group` column)**

```
=INDEX(C4:C33,MATCH(MIN(ABS(A4:A33-F5)),ABS(A4:A33-F5),0))
```

Comment: What's the expected answer given the criteria in your example?

Comment: Example in the image {group=3, value=8.01} = 'bigger'.   
Another example can be {group=1, value=3.00} = 'Chinese'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a go...it seems to work on my test sheet.  Be sure to adjust the ranges to suit your situation.  Again, this is an array formula and needs to be confirmed with Ctrl+Shift+Enter:

```
=INDEX(C2:C7,MATCH(MIN(ABS((B2:B7=F4)*A2:A7-F5)),ABS((B2:B7=F4)*A2:A7-F5),0),0)
```

It works by zeroing out keys that don't match your group assignment (that's the (B2:B7=F4)*A2:A7-F5) part.  So only keys w/ valid groups have some number to be used to match to the data column.

Hope that helps explain it.  You can also utilize the "Evaluate Formula" function on the Formulas toolbar to see it in action.

Note - it seems to return the 1st data value if 0 is used as the closest value (regardless of group selection).  Not sure how to get around that...

Comment: I believe this is the best answer (almost had it posted myself!). However, it would be better to wrap the `ABS()` arrays in `IFERROR()` functions. Then the `Key` column could include blank cells, and the columns would not have to be adjusted every time the length of the data changes. Like so: `=INDEX(Data,MATCH(MIN(IFERROR(ABS((GroupNo=Group)*Key-DecimalValue)," ")),IFERROR(ABS((GroupNo=Group)*Key-DecimalValue)," "),0))` (note that `GroupNo` is the Group number column, `Group` is the designated group for searching).

Answer (score 2):

Here is sous2817's answer adjusted to avoid the problem of getting the wrong result when entering 0:

```
=INDEX(Data,MATCH(MIN(IFERROR(ABS(IF(GroupNo=Group,1," ")*Key-DecimalValue),
" ")),IFERROR(ABS(IF(GroupNo=Group,1," ")*Key-DecimalValue)," "),0))
```

The explanation for how it works is the same. The problem is avoided by replacing zeroes with errors.

Note that `Key` is the key column, `GroupNo` is the Group number column, `Data` is the data column, `Group` is the designated group for searching, and  `DecimalNumber` is the number entered for searching.

EDIT: As discussed in comments below, this formula can be made much more readable by using a named range (AKA named formula). Set a named range `searchRange` equal to:

```
IFERROR(ABS(IF(GroupNo=Group,1," ")*Key-DecimalValue)," ")
```

Then the formula becomes:

```
=INDEX(Data,MATCH(MIN(searchRange),searchRange,0))
```

This has the added benefit of less Excel overhead, since the named formula only gets calculated once (whereas in the other version, it is calculated every time it appears).

Comment: You don't, actually. Just use a named range. Like so:
Set `searchRange` equal to `IFERROR(ABS(IF(GroupNo=Group,1," ")*Key-DecimalValue)," ")`
Formula is now:
`=INDEX(Data,MATCH(MIN(searchRange),searchRange,0))`. `searchRange` is only evaluated by Excel once. :)

Comment: Now THIS is a beautiful answer. I really need to learn to use named (calculated) ranges... I have only ever used them statically. This was my "learning moment" for the day. Thank you!

Comment: They're very powerful. Just be careful not to make them volatile (use `INDEX()` and `MATCH()` instead of `OFFSET()`, `INDIRECT()`, etc etc), and do not set them so they are crunching entire columns, e.g. `A:A`. You will regret it later.... slooooooooooooow spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do as follows

```
Function getLastRow()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim l_row As Integer
    For i = 1 To 35
        If Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row > l_row Then
            l_row = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
        End If
    Next i
    getLastRow = l_row
End Function
Sub data_lookup
    Dim last_row As Integer
    Dim lcell as Range
    Dim col_a_lookup As Double
    Dim col_b_lookup AS Double
    Dim row_collection As New Collection
    Dim variance AS Double
    Dim closest_row AS Integer

    col_b_lookup = 0.04
    col_a_lookup = 8
    variance = 50

    last_row = getLastRow
    'Find All the Cells that match your lookup value for column B
    For Each lcell in Sheet1.Range("$B$2", "$B$" & last_row)
       If lcell.value = col_b_lookup Then
          row_collection.Add lcell
       End If
    Next lcell
    'Loop through the collection created above to find the closest absolute value to
    'your lookup value for Column A 
    For Each lcell in row_collection
        If Abs(Sheet1.Cells(lcell.row,"A") - col_a_lookup) < variance then
            variance = Abs(Sheet1.Cells(lcell.row,"A") - col_a_lookup)
            closest_row = lcell.row
        End If
    Next lcell
    'Return Results 
    If closest_row > 0 Then
        Msgbox "Closest Data: " & Sheet1.Cells(closest_row,"G")
    Else
        Msgbox "Cannot Locate"
    End If
End Sub
```

Obviously you will have to set `col_a_lookup` and `col_b_lookup` to the values specified and I am sure you want to change the Msgbox. But this should help you on your way.